# Computer wont start (even to bios)

Tags: windows-8, boot, cpu, motherboard, bios

My laptop (Lenovo G580) just wont start. I can't enter even to BIOS. 
With power supply everything is OK. I tried to boot w\out battery. Nothing changes.
RAM: 4GB.
laptop is Not overclocked.
I also tried to replace CMOS battery. again, nothing changed!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHVSj.jpg]

When i press a random key at the "console" screen, it beeps.
Any help?

Comment: I would contact the Lenovo Support

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a motherboard coponent has gone bad. Contact vendor.

Comment: Agreed.  If the thing is wet, you could see if it works better when it dries up.  Probably won't.  Otherwise, you'll need to replace the metherboard or whatever chip is bad.  However, replacing chips is not a typical repair activity: some chips are "permanently" attached and are not meant to be removable.  Usual process is to replace entire motherboard component.  Alternative: you could *try* replacing a RAM chip, or removing one RAM chip if you have multiple.  That might be reasonably easy, and could fix this issue.  But is a bit of a long shot; not worth buying more RAM just to try.